# BG95 Can't Activate - AT+QIACT=1 returning error

Tags: quectel

I'm trying to get a BG95 to activate on hologram.

Here are my commands:
AT+QCFG="band",F,180A,180A   OK

AT+QCFG="iotopmode",2    OK

AT+QCFG="nwscanseq",020301     OK

AT+QCFG="nwscanmode",0    OK

AT+QCFG="snrscan",0    OK

AT+QICSGP=1,1,"hologram","","",1    OK

AT+QIACT=1    ERROR

At first I thought it was antenna/signal related so I ran AT+CSQ and got this:
+csq: 11,99

This tells me I have a good signal I believe.

Next I tried AT+QNWINFO and get this:
+QNWINFO: "eMTC","311480","LTE BAND 13",5230

In my mind this is saying it's connected to a network.

After trying that I tried to activate again and got this:
AT+QIACT=1
ERROR

The weird thing is it activated just fine about a week ago with pure AT commands. I did try and use an Arduino library with it (WisLTEBG96TCPIP) which may have changed a setting in it. I've done a factory reset but the it still woln't activate.

Another strange thing is the hologram dashboard. Every once and a while it will show the SIM as connected, even though I can't activate.

I have tried with 2 different SIM cards any get the same activation error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you resolve this? I have same issue with Sierra Wireless IoT SIM

Answer (score 1):

Verizon has cut off all non ODI products. If your hardware has not been Verizon ODI 'certified' it will no longer be allow to be connected to their network, I have 5 new pet rocks thanks to them. The solution is to purchase new modems from vendors that have been through the Verizon ODI program or switch carriers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before, after a lot of maling with network operator I find out that there isn't a LTE-CAT-M1 (eMTC) network in my area, I tested in another area successfully

Also before setting AT+QCFG commands try AT+CFUN = 0
and after setting AT+QCFG commands try AT+CFUN = 1 .

before sending AT+QIACT, try 'AT+CEREG?' command several times and tell me what is the return of it